# Reversing a colormap produced by Blend

Tags: graphics, color

Is there a way to reverse a colormap that is produced by the command `Blend`?

In particular I wanted to reverse the parula colormap given in this [link](https://tpfto.wordpress.com/2018/03/05/on-emulating-the-parula-colormap-in-mathematica/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
parulaColorList = {{0, RGBColor[0.2422, 0.1504, 0.6603]}, {2/255, 
    RGBColor[0.2464, 0.1569, 0.6847]}, {4/255, 
    RGBColor[0.2503, 0.1648, 0.7071]}, {3/85, 
    RGBColor[0.2594, 0.1854, 0.761]}, {14/255, 
    RGBColor[0.2676, 0.2052, 0.8148]}, {16/255, 
    RGBColor[0.2704, 0.2138, 0.8346]}, {19/255, 
    RGBColor[0.274, 0.228, 0.8612]}, {7/85, 
    RGBColor[0.2758, 0.2382, 0.8767]}, {8/85, 
    RGBColor[0.2781, 0.2543, 0.8973]}, {26/255, 
    RGBColor[0.2794, 0.2653, 0.9094]}, {29/255, 
    RGBColor[0.2806, 0.2819, 0.9255]}, {31/255, 
    RGBColor[0.2811, 0.293, 0.9352]}, {7/51, 
    RGBColor[0.2813, 0.315, 0.9524]}, {8/51, 
    RGBColor[0.2798, 0.3421, 0.9702]}, {44/255, 
    RGBColor[0.2766, 0.3638, 0.9817]}, {47/255, 
    RGBColor[0.2726, 0.3804, 0.9881]}, {10/51, 
    RGBColor[0.267, 0.3973, 0.9924]}, {11/51, 
    RGBColor[0.2517, 0.4261, 0.9974]}, {59/255, 
    RGBColor[0.2311, 0.4497, 0.9995]}, {21/85, 
    RGBColor[0.2066, 0.4743, 0.9926]}, {67/255, 
    RGBColor[0.1869, 0.4975, 0.9844]}, {24/85, 
    RGBColor[0.1795, 0.5244, 0.9709]}, {76/255, 
    RGBColor[0.1768, 0.5452, 0.956]}, {16/51, 
    RGBColor[0.1716, 0.5655, 0.9393]}, {1/3, 
    RGBColor[0.154, 0.5902, 0.9218]}, {88/255, 
    RGBColor[0.1475, 0.6043, 0.9113]}, {92/255, 
    RGBColor[0.1408, 0.6226, 0.8998]}, {98/255, 
    RGBColor[0.1219, 0.6497, 0.8862]}, {101/255, 
    RGBColor[0.1119, 0.6627, 0.877]}, {106/255, 
    RGBColor[0.0914, 0.6828, 0.8562]}, {22/51, 
    RGBColor[0.0628, 0.6972, 0.8355]}, {38/85, 
    RGBColor[0.0234, 0.7103, 0.8124]}, {39/85, 
    RGBColor[0.0046, 0.7192, 0.7941]}, {121/255, 
    RGBColor[0.0046, 0.7301, 0.7688]}, {41/85, 
    RGBColor[0.0162, 0.7352, 0.7558]}, {42/85, 
    RGBColor[0.0504, 0.7423, 0.7359]}, {128/255, 
    RGBColor[0.077, 0.7468, 0.7224]}, {44/85, 
    RGBColor[0.1252, 0.7552, 0.695]}, {137/255, 
    RGBColor[0.1678, 0.7656, 0.6599]}, {48/85, 
    RGBColor[0.2061, 0.7808, 0.6065]}, {146/255, 
    RGBColor[0.2178, 0.7849, 0.5899]}, {148/255, 
    RGBColor[0.2318, 0.7887, 0.5725]}, {10/17, 
    RGBColor[0.2491, 0.7922, 0.5546]}, {3/5, 
    RGBColor[0.2809, 0.7964, 0.5266]}, {52/85, 
    RGBColor[0.3176, 0.7994, 0.4975]}, {158/255, 
    RGBColor[0.3424, 0.8009, 0.4774]}, {161/255, 
    RGBColor[0.3795, 0.8026, 0.4454]}, {163/255, 
    RGBColor[0.405, 0.8031, 0.4233]}, {11/17, 
    RGBColor[0.4322, 0.8028, 0.4013]}, {167/255, 
    RGBColor[0.4608, 0.8018, 0.3797]}, {169/255, 
    RGBColor[0.4899, 0.8002, 0.3586]}, {173/255, 
    RGBColor[0.547, 0.7957, 0.3159]}, {176/255, 
    RGBColor[0.5886, 0.7913, 0.2833]}, {178/255, 
    RGBColor[0.6161, 0.7878, 0.2622]}, {12/17, 
    RGBColor[0.6433, 0.7839, 0.2423]}, {61/85, 
    RGBColor[0.6833, 0.7773, 0.2155]}, {62/85, 
    RGBColor[0.7218, 0.7703, 0.1924]}, {63/85, 
    RGBColor[0.759, 0.7629, 0.1717]}, {191/255, 
    RGBColor[0.7829, 0.7579, 0.1608]}, {194/255, 
    RGBColor[0.8172, 0.7505, 0.1535]}, {196/255, 
    RGBColor[0.8389, 0.7457, 0.1546]}, {40/51, 
    RGBColor[0.8804, 0.7372, 0.165]}, {202/255, 
    RGBColor[0.9, 0.7336, 0.1749]}, {41/51, 
    RGBColor[0.9272, 0.7298, 0.1973]}, {206/255, 
    RGBColor[0.9357, 0.729, 0.2061]}, {209/255, 
    RGBColor[0.9606, 0.7285, 0.2312]}, {14/17, 
    RGBColor[0.9689, 0.7292, 0.2373]}, {212/255, 
    RGBColor[0.9842, 0.733, 0.2446]}, {71/85, 
    RGBColor[0.99, 0.7365, 0.2429]}, {43/51, 
    RGBColor[0.9966, 0.7458, 0.2351]}, {217/255, 
    RGBColor[0.9972, 0.7569, 0.2267]}, {74/85, 
    RGBColor[0.9957, 0.7856, 0.2053]}, {15/17, 
    RGBColor[0.9923, 0.8034, 0.1939]}, {229/255, 
    RGBColor[0.9835, 0.828, 0.1817]}, {236/255, 
    RGBColor[0.9651, 0.8716, 0.1608]}, {16/17, 
    RGBColor[0.9601, 0.8963, 0.1507]}, {242/255, 
    RGBColor[0.9595, 0.9084, 0.145]}, {82/85, 
    RGBColor[0.9618, 0.932, 0.1304]}, {83/85, 
    RGBColor[0.9657, 0.9494, 0.1168]}, {1, 
    RGBColor[0.9769, 0.9839, 0.0805]}};
```

---

```
parulaNew = Blend[parulaColorList, #1] &;
parulaReverse = Blend[parulaColorList, 1 - #1] &;
```

[image]

Comment: Endorsing this solution. ;)